# how to remove 12PM from x axis in d3 grouped area chart?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

image link: https://ibb.co/yXSf27y

So basically 12PM is showing up at x axis when the data is around 7 days. i want to remove the 12PM. The code is in Nuxt JS and the chart library is d3-vs. specifically it is a d3-grouped-area chart.
below is the code:

```
            optionsAreas:{
                fill: (d) => {
                    d.opacity = 1
                    return this.scopeColors[d.label]
                },
                groupAreaTitle: (d) => {
                    return moment(d.key).format('MMM DD') + "<br/>"+this.companyDetails.form_fields.turnover.currency + " " + numeral(d.value).format('0.00')
                },
                areaTitle: (d) => {
                    // console.log(d)
                    return "currency:" + d.value

                },
                axisYLabel: "€",
                axisYLaneWidth: 30,
                yAxisRuler: true,
                axisXGroupLabelGap: 30,
                xTickFormat: (d) => {//this is what i have tried but it is of no use
                const hour = d.getHours();
                return hour === 0 ? '' : "aa"// d3.timeFormat('%I %p')(d);
                }
            },
```

and the chart is made using:

```
</div>
                                <d3-grouped-area
                                    :data="dataMonthlyCost"
                                    :options="optionsAreas"
                                    :margin="margin"
                                    width="100%"
                                    height="450px"
                                >
                                </d3-grouped-area>
```

Edit:
when 1 day is selected then it is showing 3pm, 6pm, 9pm etc. I want to remove time and just show dates. how is it possible?